# How would TIMTHUMB.PHP affect the SEO of a website, or Image SEO

Tags: php, seo, search-engine

If I use timthumb.php for reducing images and posting them automatically with the appropiate size on my website sounds fantastic. Saves a lot of work.

But would that affect the results in http://images.google.com ?
Let's say I have a photo named "my-dalmatian-dog.jpg" and then I apply tinthumb.php..it would be changed to some other name...and I dont know if the search results would be that great.

what would be the result of using this, in terms of SEO ?

Comment: title="<?=$original_file_name;?>" ?

Comment: I dont think adding the title would do any good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always rewrite your URLs so that they look like the original. For example, you could make `timthumb.php?filename=my-dalmatian-dog.jpg` look like `/images/thumb/my-dalmatian-dog.jpg` using an Apache rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^images/thumb/(.*) timthumb.php?filename=$1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I know how to do ReWrites on .htaccess and I couldn't think of this. Thanks.

Comment: this is intelligent, however how will google deal with this - currently it shows the image as a php file

what if we do this a 301 etc redirect to this - will that effect the seo?

anyways thanks!

Comment: Some has a solution its not given complete at http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1862282#post14924421

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out on how to redirect it albeit then it doesn't covert the images... I mean it redirects to the image source but simultaneously it doesn't resize them...

```
RewriteRule ^[-a-z0-9_]+/[-a-z0-9_]+/([0-9]+)/?$ /story.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?src=(.*)&w=(.*)&h=(.*)&zc=(.*)&q=(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/timthumb\.php)?$ %2 [R=301,L]
```

Seems like it has to be done from within the timthumb.php file itself. It gotta see when an image is being called to resize and when is it called for indexing by robots etc...

Can anyone find a flexible solution here?